# C++ class template for similar classes

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have a socket data type class that is used to read and parse a value from socket stream (may be used for file too).
Let my class be `mc_double`:

```
class mc_double {
    private:
           double value;
    public:
           bool read(socket);
           write(double);
}
```

Actual class is more complicated, but this is the principle. Now, I need to parse `float` from the stream. Float is way similar to double, so is already implemented `int`. Could't I merge this class definitions, with all `double`, `int` and `float` somehow templated?

This is what I mean:

```
 class mc_<typename = double or int or float> {
    private:
           typename value;
    public:
           bool read(socket);
           write(typename);
}
```

Some methods would be then defined individualy as `mc_double::method()` others would be same for all types: `mc_typename::general_method()`. Also, for some I'd need just minor changes in code:

```
typename mc_typename::return_value() {
         return val;
}
```

Or the constructor:

```
mc_typename::mc_typename(<int, long, char, double> number) {
        val = (typename)number;
}
```

The result should be **three** classes - `mc_int`, `mc_float` and `mc_double`.
I have found the official C++ template docs, but I only figured out the last part of my question - I can create a function that accepts multiple data types. The rest does not seem to be that easy.

Comment: I strongly suggest a good book on C++ templates.

Comment: A whole book would be probably too much; however a simple tutorial-ish overview like [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) would not harm for sure.

Comment: @ulidtko: This is just what I've read. This is what I meant by the "*official C++ template docs*".

Comment: There is nothing official about cplusplus.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your class a class template:

```
template<typename T, bool base = true>
class mc {
protected:
   T value;
public:
   bool read(socket);
   write(T);
};
```

This class will contain the member function that are common for all types `T`. Then, you could specialize this class templates separately for different types *and* let them inherit from `mc<T, true>`:

```
template<>
class mc<double, true> : public mc<double, false> {
public:
    // Member functions for double only...
};

template<>
class mc<int, true> : public mc<int, false> {
public:
    // Member functions for int only...
};
```

Make sure the non-public member data of the primary class template are made `protected` if you want derived classes to access them.

You could then instantiate them this way:

```
mc<double> m;
mc<int> m;
// ...
```

If you really want to use the `mc_double` and `mc_int` names, then you could either:

a) Create type aliases for them:

```
typedef mc<double> mc_double;
typedef mc<int> mc_int;
```

b) Change the design of the class template to not use specialization and have one single template parameter, and create the derived classes independently:

```
template<typename T>
class mc {
protected:
   T value;
public:
   bool read(socket);
   write(T);
};

class mc_double : public mc<double> {
public:
    // Member functions for double only...
};

class mc_int: public mc<int> {
public:
    // Member functions for int only...
};
```

Comment: Thank you, though I hate to find out it will not be that simple. May I ask you what that `true` in `<double, true>` is?

Comment: Nice use of the base parameter; hadn't thought of doing that to override specific functions

Comment: @TomášZato: That's just a trick which I use for class template specialization, but I admit it's not that intuitive. If you find that unclear, you could still use the second alternative solution in my answer, which is simpler

Comment: "*If you find that unclear*" - I prefer searching answers than avoiding questions :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `base` parameter?

Comment: @TomášZato: That's the spirit :) Basically, the template parameter takes a default value of `true`. This means that specifying `mc<double>` is the same as specifying `mc<double, true>`. Now because of the way class template specialization works, the specialization for `<double, true>` will be instantiated instead of the primary template. This specialization in turn inherits from `mc<double, false>`, for which there is no specialization (because of the boolean argument): thus, `mc<double, false>` refers to an instantiation of the primary template.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: See the explanation in the previous comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use templates in the class definition as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class mc
{
public:
   bool write(T _val);

private:
   T mVal;
};
```

but you can't as easily specialize some methods but not others based on the type of T (i.e., you have to specialize the entire class, not just one method). You could solve this with some sort of inheritance hierarchy, where methods that are the same regardless of the type are in the base, and the specialization is in derived classes. So keep the above (assuming `write` is one that doesn't change) and create:

```
class mc_double : public mc<double>
{
public:
    void doSomethingSpecific() { /* code specific for 'doubles' */ }
};
```